# Unable to update value in view despite using two way binding

Tags: html, angular, typescript, two-way-binding

I am attempting to two-way bind between the HTML and the TS. The goal is that when the user clicks the getAddress button, the TS automatically populates the input box of Address 1 and Address 2 after obtaining the information. As such, the user does not need to type the address out manually. Unfortunately, when the address values are updated, the view does not update with the new values despite using NgModel. How do I notify the view to update the input box when it receives a new value?

```js
public async getCurrentAddress() {
    // variables
    const geolocationService = this.geolocationService
    let address1 = this.address1;
    let address2 = this.address2;
    const address = geolocationService.getAddressOfCurrentLocation()
    
    // the TS variables address1 and address 2 values updates but the view does not update with the new values
    address1 = address[0]
    address2 = address[1]
 }
```

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Enter Address 1</ion-label>
  <ion-input placeholder="Enter your address 1" [(ngModel)]="address1"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Enter Address 2</ion-label>
  <ion-input placeholder="Enter your address 2" [(ngModel)]="address2"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Never used the Ionic Framework, but it looks like you can use [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#value) property. You clearly know how to bind properties in Angular, but for others viewing this question, see [this](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding). You should include the version of Angular in your question. I didn't test my answer, but if it works, please let me know and I will post it as an answer for record.

Comment: if 'geolocationService.getAddressOfCurrentLocation()' is a promise, you need either do await its response, or only assign the variables on the "then" method

Comment: There are no issues with geolocationService.getAddressOfCurrentLocation(), It is able to return the necessary information.

Comment: Shouldn't you write `this.address1 = address[0]` instead of `address1 = address[0]`? Otherwise you only update the variable inside the method and not the global variable that is accessible via `ngModel`.

Comment: Thank you, you solve it. I can't believe I didn't realise it.